# Where to store my text variables (book's worth of text) and how to access them

Tags: kotlin, import

For legibility reasons (and the fact that I'm too new at this to learn how to do it via JSON parsing) I have a 500 element array. Each element contains basically a paragraph of text. I'm setting them manually one by one because I may need to edit the text etc and it will help me finding what needs changing.

My `pNums` variable will hold all the paragraphs.

In my `MainActivity.kt` I declare `var pNums =  arrayOfNulls<String>(500)` along with my other variables. I don't want to have all my variables in this file. I tried to put them inside a different class file, but I don't think I understand scope that well yet, and I was not able to set any of my `pNums` like I could from inside of the MainActivity class.

What kind of file do I need to create to hold all my text? I'm guessing I need to create a file and import it in the `MainActivity.kt`?

Comment: I'd suggest you use a `List` instead of an `Array`. Arrays in Kotlin are more for historical reasons, Java compatibility, and low-level implementation of classes like `ArrayList`; lists are much more flexible and powerful. For one thing, they can be resized: you don't need to pre-size them and fill them with nulls.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick a `val` inside another file if you want, so long as you import it (like anything else) you can access it from `MainActivity`. If you define it inside another class, you either need to have an instance of that class so you can access the `val` (like `myThing.pNums`) or it needs to be inside a `companion object` which lets you access properties and functions on the class itself (like `ThingClass.pNums`) instead of having to create an instance of `ThingClass`

Here's the details if you care about all that:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html
but you can just stick it in the top level of a file too (not inside a class or object)

At some point you'll probably want to keep this as a text file, read in as chunks split on paragraph breaks or something, that way you can edit it in a text editor which will be way nicer than wrangling arrays. But you can figure that out when you're ready! Plenty of tutorials out there

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new Kotlin class called `ParagraphResolver.kt` and have the following in it:

```
public class ParagraphResolver {
    public val Paragraphs: Array<String> = arrayOf("paragraph1", "paragraph2")
}
```

Then to get your paragraphs in `MainActivity.kt` you can get the value like so:

```
val paragraphs = ParagraphResolver().Paragraphs
```